# building a calendar display for Case records in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, calendar

I am looking into attempting to build a custom tab that will display Case records in a monthly calendar view using visualforce. something like the below standard event calendar view.
[image: example - standard event calendar view]

I am looking at the code for the Milestones PM calendar page as an example but this is far more complex than what i need. Does anyone know of a more basic sample that i could learn from?

Comment: Have you considered using Full calendar in your VF page. The above screenshot looks very similar to what you can get out of Full calendar : http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Comment: http://developer.force.com/projectpage?id=a0630000002ahp6AAA    Something to start ...

Comment: Thanks Rao, i'm a button click admin so development is more of a cut and paste exercise for me.

Mohith, this looks familiar to me as its in apex and VF already, currently getting it into the IDE so i can start playing. Thanks.

Comment: If you did decide to go the fullcalendar route, here are a couple of blog posts that might help you: http://force201.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/fullcalendar-quick-start/, http://force201.wordpress.com/2013/01/26/fullcalendar-using-a-javascript-remoting-callback/.